# Python re search between string and first occurence of second string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which returns every occurrence of a string between two given strings. The problem is that when it finds the first string, it searches from right to left for the second string.

For example in the string `"This 1 is 2 an 1 example 2."` I'd like it to return everything between 1 and 2 so `" is "` and `" example "`, but it returns `" is 2 an 1 example "`.

I also can't know how many results it will return and the string between '1' and '2' can contain letters, numbers and whitespaces.

What I've tried: `(1(.+)+2)+`

code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(1(.+)+2)+')
matches = pattern.finditer(file)
```

Comment: You have to use a non greedy quantifier `\b1( .+? )2\b` https://regex101.com/r/dPm9lP/1

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird, that was indeed my mistake